# How to set line break with HTML composed e-mail in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

I cannot make Thunderbird break lines in my E-mail to specified length when they are composed in HTML, even after I did the following:

the "mailnews.wraplength" in Edit->Preferences->Advanced->Config Editor is set to 80, as well as the boolean "mail.wrap_long_lines" which is set to true. Also, I have set the "mail.compose.wrap_to_window_length" to false. Still, lines in the HTML composed E-mail are broken at window length, even after restarting Thunderbird.

I have installed the "Toggle Text Wrap" addon and it's working fine, but this means I need to compose E-mail in text mode. Is it possible to make Thunderbird split up endless, non-readible lines when using composing in HTML and with pre-scribed fixed width?

Edit: Is there a way to set the window size when I start composing e-mails, so that the line breaking that is somehow fixed to the window size, works on a smaller window?

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the question in the topic is:

In order to set break for html you will have to use 
`<br>` tag, for simple text you will have to use `\n`.

For your edit question, the way I may think of is using a div which contains your text, you can give it a width (and a height if you would like to).

```
<div style="width:400px;" >You text here! </div>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Should I write this within my e-mail? I'm confused, since this is html, and what I actually need is the line of text to simply break into a new line after N characters, within the Thunderbird editor, as I am writing it...

Comment: @tomislav-maric if you email is html you add `<br>` after N characters.

Comment: Hm... when I say I'm composing in html, I mean that I have chosen the option in "Account Settings -> Composition and Addresing" ("Compose in Html"). I'm not actually writing my e-mail in HTML. I don't get it... :)

Comment: did you try to write your email and add `<br>` and see the results ?

Comment: Of course I did, but adding <br> within a text editor in Thunderbird does nothing. I just have <br> inside the text. What I need is a functioning E-mail client that allows me to set the text width, and justifies the text (left, right, centered, etc). :)

Comment: If your email is in html format, you can wrap your text within a div as I told you in my answer.